# jquery append image is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append an image inside a slider on my website. I am doing that way because the image urls are coming from an external json.

The problem is: sometimes the image loads fine. Sometimes I need to refresh the page a couple of times to get it loaded.
Is there any way to force it to load? or another way to fix this problem?

My code:

```
var qtd_slides = infosEvento.slides.length;
      for(i = 0; i < qtd_slides; i++){
            var nomeFeiradebug = jQuery("#slider_feira").append('<li class="item format-image"><img src="http://www.reedalcantara.com.br'+infosEvento.slides[i].url+'"></li>'); 
            jQuery("#slider_feira").append('<li class="item format-image"><img src="http://www.reedalcantara.com.br'+infosEvento.slides[i].url+'"></li>'); 
      }
```

Here's the page link:
http://bit.ly/1Ikx3G0
Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: please post the relevant code here, also, take a look in the developer toolbar, there you can see all requests thats loaded and where in the javascript it executes :)

Comment: I've updated the question with the code that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

check this code i think this will help you

```
$('<img src="'+ imgPaht +'">').load(function() {
  $(this).width(some).height(some).appendTo('#some_target');
});
```

Comment: I guess my problem is releated with the slider plugin. If the plugin loads before the image, the dynamic image doesn't appear as it doesn't has time to be loaded in the DOM. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I got your point...tried your code but didn't solve the problem. Thanks anyway.